# Editing a closed question

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705470/sic-xe-assembler) was already closed  (since the question was unclear). I edited that question now. They said my edit will be placed in the queue since I don't have editing privileges.  Will this edit be taken into account?

Will the question be reopened? And I can't see my edited version now. But when I edited the question,  I saw the edited version. I left the one requirements of the original author. I want to edit the question again.

But I now can see only the older version of the question. What I should do now?

Comment: There is no pending edit for that question, and it has not been edited as far as I can tell (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5705470/revision) - did you link the right question?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with the question being closed or not. Since you do not have the [editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) (given when you reach 2k rep), your edits are put into a "suggested edit" queue and must be approved by two users who do have that privilege before they are applied.

In this case, your suggested edits were not really the kind of edits that are encouraged here. They expand so much upon the original question:

> i wanted the idea of the code for sic/xe 2pass assembler that gives the object code for a given input program ,it also considers literals

that they amount to putting words in the asker's mouth. As a reviewer, looking at your edit, I simply say to myself "How on earth does EAGER_STUDENT think he knows what user713699 wants?" As the edit guidelines state, your edits should be primarily about correcting grammar, spelling, tagging, and clarification *if appropriate*. You should not be adding material to the question, except perhaps in the case where the OP has provided important information in a comment and failed to edit it into the body.

The original question makes no mention of "simulation", but you have added (and misspelled) that word multiple times in these suggested edits. Your first edit removes the mention of "literals"; both add a mention of "simpler". Both edits contain poor grammar and spelling. This is not in itself a reason to reject -- it's possible to revise your edit -- but it certainly makes your suggestion less useful, since it adds work for reviewers. Both of your edits add "Thanks in advance.", which is [considered noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), something to be edited *out* of posts, not added. Your edits repeat the "from experts" phrase and others, also creating noise.

In short, your suggestions were reviewed, and rejected because they did not make the question better. Let me say, however, that although still not acceptable, your second suggested edit is better than the first.

---

Suggested edit 1:

> I am about to write a stimulating program for SIC / XE assembler in
>   c/c++ language. But since it is more complex to write an entire
>   algorithm for SIC / XE assembler, I want to stimulate in a simple
>   manner.
>
> But to do so, I need assistance form experts,that how can I stimulate
>   the SIC / XE assembler, such that it converts the given source code to
>   the object code.
>
> What are the simple operations that I can do in the conversion
>   algorithm.
>
> Needed explanations form experts.
>
> Thanks in advance.

---

Suggested edit 2:

> I want to stimulate a the SIC / XE assembler in a simpler manner in
>   c/c++.
>
> For that , I need a general idea from experts about how could I do
>   that.
>
> My SIC / XE assembler should include the feature of manipulating the
>   literals too.
>
> How could I achieve it?
>
> Needed suggestions form experts.
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of your answer is correct, however I disagree about asking myself "How on earth does EAGER_STUDENT think he knows what user713699 wants?" If the *original* question is useless and utterly incomprehensible, and someone else comes along to improve it so that it *is* (or might be) useful and at least makes sense, **I'll vote to approve that edit every time**. I'm more interested in improving the community overall than getting an answer for someone who doesn't take any more time to compose their questions than that.

Answer (score 0):

Editing closed questions works the same as editing open questions; your edit will be applied as soon as a moderator approves it. I'm not a moderator, but perhaps someone who is can tell you the current status of your edit.

The question will be reopened if enough users think it should be; it needs to get five re-open votes (you can cast one yourself, the four others must come from users with enough reputation).

Comment: I cant see the edited version now. I left the one requirements of the original author. I want to edit the question again. what i could do now?